# Format operator output

Tags: output-formatting

I have been working with non-commuting algebra, which is indicated in Mathematica by `**`. However, I want to suppress the `**` from the output. Consider:

```
n = 4;    
Sum[Binomial[n, r] b^r ** a^(n - r), {r, 0, n}]
```

which gives

```
1 ** a^4 + 4 b ** a^3 + 6 b^2 ** a^2 + 4 b^3 ** a + b^4 ** 1
```

Note that all b's appear to the left of any a's. This is since they do **not** commute. Instead of the output above, I want to drop the `**` to instead have:

```
a^4 + 4 b a^3 + 6 b^2 a^2 + 4 b^3 a + b^4
```

since it is better suited when `n` becomes large.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following code is close to what you want:

```
With[{n = 4}, Sum[Binomial[n, r] b^r ** a^(n - r), {r, 0, n}]]
  /. {NonCommutativeMultiply -> Dot} // InputForm
```

with resulting output

```
1 . a^4 + 4*b . a^3 + 6*b^2 . a^2 + 4*b^3 . a + b^4 . 1
```

You could use `TradtionalForm` instead which results in a more compact outuput.